# QuickBlox iOS WebRTC Video View Size

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I'm trying to get my QBRTCRemoteVideoView to present a full-screen video output, similar to FaceTime or Skype.

However, using AutoLayout in my project, and setting the constraints to lead and trail to the superview, the video I get back does not follow those constraints. It shows with black borders on the top and bottom.

Even using the following properties:

```
videoFormat.width = 320; // or anything
videoFormat.height = 568; // or anything
```

Does not seem to change the dimensions of the video. Any advice for me here on controlling the video output view?

Answer (score 0):

You can only set a specific width and height for video, to see what kind of video formats are supported by your device, call:

```
[QBRTCCameraCapture formatsWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];
// or AVCaptureDevicePositionBack
// or just get the currentPosition from your QBRTCCameraCapture instance
```